# How to read ORC files without metastore in pyspark 2.0

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, orc

I want to read some ORC files using pyspark 2.0 without metastore. Theoretically, it is feasible to do so, because data schema is embedded in ORC file. But here is what I got:

```
[me@hostname ~]$/usr/local/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/pyspark
Python 2.7.11 (default, Feb 18 2016, 13:54:48)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel).
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.0.0
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.11 (default, Feb 18 2016 13:54:48)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> df=spark.read.orc('/my/orc/file')
16/08/21 22:29:38 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/08/21 22:30:00 ERROR metastore.RetryingHMSHandler: AlreadyExistsException(message:Database default already exists)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.create_database(HiveMetaStore.java:891)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:107)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.create_database(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createDatabase(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:644)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:156)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.createDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createDatabase(Hive.java:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$createDatabase$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveClientImpl.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$createDatabase$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$createDatabase$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.liftedTree1$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:209)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.retryLocked(HiveClientImpl.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.withHiveState(HiveClientImpl.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.createDatabase(HiveClientImpl.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$createDatabase$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$createDatabase$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$createDatabase$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.createDatabase(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.createDatabase(SessionCatalog.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.(SessionCatalog.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionCatalog.(HiveSessionCatalog.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSessionState.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.catalog(HiveSessionState.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState$$anon$1.(HiveSessionState.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.analyzer$lzycompute(HiveSessionState.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.analyzer(HiveSessionState.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.baseRelationToDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:382)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.orc(DataFrameReader.scala:450)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.orc(DataFrameReader.scala:439)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:128)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:211)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

>>>
```

What's the right way to read the ORC files?

Comment: What makes you think problem is specific to ORC?

Comment: doesnt it say the error there `ERROR metastore.RetryingHMSHandler: AlreadyExistsException(message:Database default already exists)`

Comment: @zero323: it's not specific to ORC. I had the same problem when reading Parquet files. So the problem is probably associated to all files with embedded schema. But the files I really want to read are in ORC format. I just don't care Parquet and other formats.

Comment: @abhiieor But the problem is, I don't have any database setup. It says "Database default already exists", but where is the default database?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem. Though pyspark reported ERROR, loading data from ORC file into the data frame didn't fail actually. Despite the error message, the returning data frame can be referenced without any problem.